# Program directly goes to else statement

Tags: java, android

When enter input and check for the result it only show the function from else. How can i fix it. it skips if and else if and directly goes to else statement.

Here is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_v);

        //start for web view
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //fit screen
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //end for web view

        //received data from search book
        String passURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

        if(passURL.matches("0-9") && passURL.length()>= 10){
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.librarything.com/isbn/" + passURL); //load website
        }else if (passURL.matches("[a-zA-Z]")){
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.librarything.com/title/" + passURL); //load website
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }
```

Comment: `passURL.matches("0-9")` will only be true if `passURL` holds the literal string `0-9`. Do you mean to match against `"[0-9]+"` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change your code to the following:

```
if(passURL.matches("[0-9]+") && passURL.length()>= 10){
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.librarything.com/isbn/" + passURL); //load website
}else if (passURL.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.librarything.com/title/" + passURL); //load website
}else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Edit: (please correct me if im wrong)

As you can see in the answer from @datenwolf you have to put [0-9] in brackets so it checks if the string contains those numbers (or letters for [a-zA-Z]).
The plus (+) is required to check if the regex matches (at least) one or multiple times

Comment: How can I add space in this else if statement for example  "tender violence" there is a space between tender and violence

Comment: @MrBee `"[a-zA-Z ]+"`

Comment: `I think you have to change your code to the following:` why ??? you need to explain your code to OP, otherwise it doesn't really teach anyone anything

Answer (score 1):

RE `0-9` with match just the string "0-9". `[a-zA-Z]` with match only a single letter. You want `matches("[0-9]{10,}")` to match at least 10 digits  (you can then also remove the length test) and `matches("[a-zA-Z]+")`.

However consider that the title of a Book may be just a number as well. Or it might contain letters from an alphabet other than latin.